# How to configure IIS for a single-page-application build with the default template on visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, react-redux, asp.net-core-mvc, single-page-application

I would like to know, how do I configure IIS for a single page application built with the default template on Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Core 2.1 and React-Redux. I have spend the last week working on this configuration but i can't figure out why it's not working . I published and deployed it on IIS. If I indicate the build folder as the Physical Path . It's showing only the header and the footer but not the content. It indicates 404 error can't find the backend API. If i indicate the root of the site where all the backend resides, it can't find reactjs build folder.

What should I do? What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

I have tried to set in the package.json the homepage: "." and homepage : "./" and homepage: "http://mysite/sitefolder", and homepage: "/" and homepage : "http://mysite/sitefolder/Clientapp/build"

I want:

.NET Core 2.1 with React-Redux to work together on IIS

Comment: Please follow these best practices to ask a clearer question so people can help you quicker. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You say it's showing the header and footer, but then say you see a 404? How is it showing anything if you got a 404?

Comment: Gabriel Luci . It means that it can not find the backend . I have configured the web.config file but still not working.